# How to merge two dataframes with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am using Pandas to merge two dataframes obtained from Psychopy.

```
y = ["key_resp_0.keys", "key_resp_0.rt"] #some columns I want in my final dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(myData)
columns = df.columns.values.tolist() 
df2 = df.reindex(columns = y, fill_value='')
df3 = pd.merge(df2,df)
```

This is the error I get:

```
type object argument after * must be an iterable, not itertools.imap
```

I checked what type of dataframes I have:

```
print(type(df))
print(type(df2))
```

This is the result:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> #df
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> #df2
```

Following some info found in other posts, I also tried to convert `df` and `df2` into tuples   and then doing the `merge`.

```
df = df.apply(tuple) 
df2 = df2.apply(tuple)
df3 = pd.merge(df2,df)
```

Then I get a different error

```
can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Do you know what could be a way to merge these two dataframes?

Comment: in merging, you have to decide which column to be merged. do you want to merge you dataframes or append one at the end of the other?

Comment: This is what I would like to do:
1) make a copy of `df` as `df2`, where `df2` has the columns in the order I specified in `y `.

However, some columns in `df` are not specificed in `y`, because I can not know them in advance. So I want to:
2) Add those columns that are in df but not in `y` at the end of `df2`, by creating `df3`.

In a schema. df3 = df2 + (df -y), in terms of columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: what you want is not merging, by creating a copy of your original df, and add extra columns, your new df as df2 is what you want without any other steps

Answer (score 0):

Check this [thread](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10783/how-do-i-merge-two-data-frames-in-python-pandas). Literally, I see this question asked every few days. Official [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) are rather covering this as well. `RTFM` bro.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I checked the thread and the docs but I don´t see any mention of the first error I am reporting. I will look at these links more deeply though.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to find a solution.

In my dataframe `df` there was a possibly empty string (when opening `df` as a .csv file, one cell contained only `[]`). Now I am assigning to that cell a value of zero and the merge function seems to work properly.